# Pax Exam execute command against Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, pax-exam, pax-runner

I am trying to run a PAX Exam test which starts a Karaf instance version 4.0.2 and then deploys some features. Everything works so far.

However, I also want to run some commands to check that the bundles have been installed i.e. run "bundle:list" command.

I have added the executeCommand and getOsgiService methods found here:
https://github.com/christian-posta/rider-auto-osgi/blob/master/itests/src/test/java/org/jboss/fuse/example/support/FuseTestSupport.java#L80

but I am getting RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.felix.service.command.CommandProcessor)
    at com.axiell.tenantidlookup.integrationtest.TenantIdLookupTest.getOsgiService(TenantIdLookupTest.java:205)
    at com.axiell.tenantidlookup.integrationtest.TenantIdLookupTest.getOsgiService(TenantIdLookupTest.java:171)
    at com.axiell.tenantidlookup.integrationtest.TenantIdLookupTest.testProvisioning(TenantIdLookupTest.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:68)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:124)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.internal.RemoteBundleContextImpl.remoteCall(RemoteBundleContextImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the code causing the exception.

```
 CommandProcessor cp = getOsgiService(CommandProcessor.class); 
        CommandSession cs = cp.createSession(System.in, System.out, System.err);
        //cs.execute("bundle:list");
        //cs.execute("wrapper:install --help");
        //System.out.println(executeCommand("bundle:list"));
        cs.close();
```

Something with the CommandProcessor is not working. Any hints or help would be appreciated. Thakns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Karaf 4.x the commands did change so you need to change it accordingly. 
A full sample can be found [here](https://github.com/ANierbeck/Karaf-Cassandra/blob/master/Karaf-Cassandra-ITest/src/test/java/de/nierbeck/cassandra/itest/TestBase.java#L140-L170)

As quick sum-up you need the SessionFactory in your test, see below:

```
@Inject
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

and from there on create a session object:

```
@Before
public void setUpITestBase() throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.create(System.in, printStream, errStream);
}
```

I did this in the before part of the test, to make sure the session is always created new.

The following is the crucial part for executing commands:

```
    String response;
    FutureTask<String> commandFuture = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            try {
                System.err.println(command);
                session.execute(command);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            printStream.flush();
            errStream.flush();
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        }
    });

    try {
        executor.submit(commandFuture);
        response = commandFuture.get(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        response = "SHELL COMMAND TIMED OUT: ";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. Does this also mean you don't need the TestProbeBuilder method?

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for the help. I had searched everywhere and to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Achim Nierbeck solved this headache for me so for reference look at his answer. If anyone just wants a peak on the code that worked for me.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.maven;
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.options.KarafDistributionOption.*;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.model.language.ConstantExpression;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.apache.karaf.features.FeaturesService;
import org.apache.karaf.features.BootFinished;
import org.apache.karaf.shell.api.console.Session;
import org.apache.karaf.shell.api.console.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Configuration;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Option;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.ProbeBuilder;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.TestProbeBuilder;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.options.LogLevelOption;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.options.WrappedUrlProvisionOption;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.Filter;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;
import org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Enumeration;

@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
public class TenantIdLookupTest {

    @Inject
    protected BundleContext bc;
    @Inject
    protected FeaturesService featuresService;
    @Inject
    protected BootFinished bootFinished;
    @Inject
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    private PrintStream errStream = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    private Session session;

    @ProbeBuilder
    public TestProbeBuilder probeConfiguration(TestProbeBuilder probe) {
        probe.setHeader(Constants.DYNAMICIMPORT_PACKAGE,
                "*,org.apache.felix.service.*;status=provisional");
        return probe;
    }

    @Configuration
    public static Option[] configure() throws Exception {
        return new Option[] {
                karafDistributionConfiguration()
                        .frameworkUrl(
                                maven().groupId("org.apache.karaf")
                                        .artifactId("apache-karaf").type("zip")
                                        .version("4.0.2"))
                        .karafVersion("4.0.2").useDeployFolder(false)
                        .unpackDirectory(new File("target/paxexam/unpack")),
                configureConsole().ignoreLocalConsole(),
                features(
                        maven().groupId("org.apache.camel.karaf")
                                .artifactId("apache-camel").type("xml")
                                .classifier("features").version("2.15.1"),
                        "camel"),
                features(
                        maven().groupId("org.apache.camel.karaf")
                                .artifactId("apache-camel").type("xml")
                                .classifier("features").version("2.15.1"),
                        "camel-blueprint"),
                features(
                        maven().groupId("org.apache.camel.karaf")
                                .artifactId("apache-camel").type("xml")
                                .classifier("features").version("2.15.1"),
                        "camel-netty4"),
                features(
                        maven().groupId("org.apache.camel.karaf")
                                .artifactId("apache-camel").type("xml")
                                .classifier("features").version("2.15.1"),
                        "camel-rabbitmq"),
                CoreOptions.mavenBundle(CoreOptions.maven(
                        "com.google.code.gson", "gson").version("2.3")),
                logLevel(LogLevelOption.LogLevel.INFO),
                // features(maven().groupId("org.apache.camel.karaf").artifactId("apache-camel").type("xml").classifier("features").version("2.12.1"),
                // "camel-blueprint", "camel-test"),
                // features(maven().groupId("net.nanthrax.blog").artifactId("camel-blueprint").type("xml").classifier("features").version("1.0-SNAPSHOT"),
                // "blog-camel-blueprint-route"),
                keepRuntimeFolder(),

        };

    }

    @Before
    public void setUpITestBase() throws Exception {
        session = sessionFactory.create(System.in, printStream, errStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProvisioning() throws Exception {
         assertTrue(featuresService.isInstalled(featuresService.getFeature("camel-blueprint")));
             System.out.println(executeCommand("bundle:list"));

    }

    protected String executeCommand(final String command) throws IOException {
        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();

        String response;
        FutureTask<String> commandFuture = new FutureTask<String>(
                new Callable<String>() {
                    public String call() {
                        try {
                            System.err.println(command);
                            session.execute(command);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                        }
                        printStream.flush();
                        errStream.flush();
                        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
                    }
                });

        try {
            executor.submit(commandFuture);
            response = commandFuture.get(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            response = "SHELL COMMAND TIMED OUT: ";
        }

        System.err.println(response);

        return response;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    protected <T> T getOsgiService(Class<T> type, String filter, long timeout) {
        ServiceTracker tracker = null;
        try {
            String flt;
            if (filter != null) {
                if (filter.startsWith("(")) {
                    flt = "(&(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS + "=" + type.getName() + ")" + filter + ")";
                } else {
                    flt = "(&(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS + "=" + type.getName() + ")(" + filter + "))";
                }
            } else {
                flt = "(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS + "=" + type.getName() + ")";
            }
            Filter osgiFilter = FrameworkUtil.createFilter(flt);
            tracker = new ServiceTracker(bc, osgiFilter, null);
            tracker.open(true);
            // Note that the tracker is not closed to keep the reference
            // This is buggy, as the service reference may change i think
            Object svc = type.cast(tracker.waitForService(timeout));
            if (svc == null) {
                Dictionary dic = bc.getBundle().getHeaders();
                System.err.println("Test bundle headers: " + explode(dic));

                for (ServiceReference ref : asCollection(bc.getAllServiceReferences(null, null))) {
                    System.err.println("ServiceReference: " + ref);
                }

                for (ServiceReference ref : asCollection(bc.getAllServiceReferences(null, flt))) {
                    System.err.println("Filtered ServiceReference: " + ref);
                }

                //logger.error("Gave up waiting for service " + flt);
                return null;
            }
            return type.cast(svc);
        } catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid filter", e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Explode the dictionary into a ,-delimited list of key=value pairs
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static String explode(Dictionary dictionary) {
        Enumeration keys = dictionary.keys();
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object key = keys.nextElement();
            result.append(String.format("%s=%s", key, dictionary.get(key)));
            if (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                result.append(", ");
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Provides an iterable collection of references, even if the original array
     * is null
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static Collection<ServiceReference> asCollection(ServiceReference[] references) {
        return references != null ? Arrays.asList(references) : Collections.<ServiceReference> emptyList();
    }

}
```

Finally the output I was waiting for:

```
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
 ID | State  | Lvl | Version      | Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  9 | Active |  80 | 2.3          | Gson
 10 | Active |  80 | 3.3.4        | RabbitMQ Java AMQP client library
 11 | Active |  80 | 4.0.26.Final | Netty/Buffer
 12 | Active |  80 | 4.0.26.Final | Netty/Codec
 13 | Active |  80 | 4.0.26.Final | Netty/Common
 14 | Active |  80 | 4.0.26.Final | Netty/Handler
 15 | Active |  80 | 4.0.26.Final | Netty/Transport
 29 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-blueprint
 30 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-catalog
 31 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-commands-core
 32 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-core
 33 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-netty4
 34 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-rabbitmq
 35 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-spring
 36 | Active |  80 | 2.15.1       | camel-karaf-commands
 37 | Active |  80 | 1.6.0        | Commons Pool
 38 | Active |  80 | 1.0          | Apache Geronimo JSR-330 Spec API
 39 | Active |  80 | 1.1.1        | geronimo-jta_1.1_spec
 69 | Active |  80 | 2.2.6.1      | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jaxb-impl
 81 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - IO
 82 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - Lang
 83 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - Monitors
 84 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - Net
 85 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - Service Provider Access
 86 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - Store
 87 | Active |  80 | 1.5.0        | OPS4J Base - Util - Property
 88 | Active |  80 | 4.6.0        | OPS4J Pax Exam API
 89 | Active |  80 | 4.6.0        | OPS4J Pax Exam Extender Service
 90 | Active |  80 | 4.6.0        | OPS4J Pax Exam Injection
 91 | Active |  80 | 4.6.0        | OPS4J Pax Exam JUnit Probe Invoker
 92 | Active |  80 | 4.6.0        | OPS4J Pax Exam Remote Bundle Context
 93 | Active |  80 | 1.8.1        | OPS4J Pax Swissbox :: OSGi Core
 94 | Active |  80 | 1.8.1        | OPS4J Pax Swissbox :: Extender
 95 | Active |  80 | 1.8.1        | OPS4J Pax Swissbox :: Framework Helpers
 96 | Active |  80 | 1.8.1        | OPS4J Pax Swissbox :: Lifecycle
 97 | Active |  80 | 1.8.1        | OPS4J Pax Swissbox :: Tracker
 98 | Active |  80 | 1.3.0.1      | OPS4J Pax Tipi - hamcrest-core
 99 | Active |  80 | 4.12.0.1     | OPS4J Pax Tipi - junit
112 | Active |  80 | 3.1.4        | Stax2 API
113 | Active |  80 | 4.4.1        | Woodstox XML-processor
114 | Active |  80 |              | PAXEXAM-PROBE-bb084675-f072-481b-8f3e-6e3657762bc3
```

Comment: When i am running above i am getting below output  14:48:20.390 [main] INFO  o.o.p.e.r.c.RemoteBundleContextClient - Waiting for remote bundle context.. on 21001 name: 52be8a65-7121-49ab-af8d-03ec1bf5b0fb timout: [ RelativeTimeout value = 180000 ]
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)